# Calculate non-elementary integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I'd like to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x^2)dx$
I think it may be possible to do it by using the fact that:
$$\int_{\gamma}^{} e^{-z^2}dz =0$$
For any closed curve $\gamma$ and that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

but I can't finish it , because I am not able to find a proper curve.How can I finish it , or is there another way to do it? Will be thankful for any clues.

Comment: OK, I've got it

Comment: Since you "got it" and there is no other answer, why don't you post your own answer to your own question? That is allowed and even encouraged at this site

Comment: Interesting connections: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral